# Understanding how to find power series around origin for given functions: $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, $\frac{1+z}{(1+z^2)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm pretty new to power series and was just looking for some guidelines to make sure that I am actually solving these correctly.

So for  $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, I guess I'm wondering if I would just solve this by setting aside the numerator and determine that  $$\frac{1+z}{1-z} =  (1+z)\frac{1}{1-z} =(1+z)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(z^k+z^{k+1})$$

And for $\frac{1+z}{(1+z^2)^3}$,
$$\frac{1+z}{(1+z^2)^3} =  (1+z)\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^3} $$
and letting $t = z^2$,
$$\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^3} =\frac{1}{(1+t)^3} = -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(1+t)^2})^{'} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+t})^{(2)} $$
where the ' and (2) are antiderivatives. From here,
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+t})^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dk^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kt^k = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}((-1)^kk(k-1)t^{k-2})$$
and I would just sub in $t = z^2$,
$$=\frac{1}{2}(1+z)\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}((-1)^kk(k-1)z^{2k-4})$$

I have no faith in my computations and what I'm doing so any pointers or advice for what I am doing would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: You deleted your question about $\sin(z-z^2)$ for no reason, so I answer your question here: yes it is $z^4/2$, I just made a typo. Your question may help others later, do not delete it just because you got the answer you were looking for.

Comment: The answer for $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ is not a power series, since it wasn’t written as $\sum a_iz^i,$ with the $a_i$ not depending on $z.$ But you can get there in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A power series around $0$ is a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_kz^k$, and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(z^k-z^{k+1})$ is not of this type. Note that\begin{align}\frac{1+z}{1-z}&=-1+2\frac1{1-z}\\&=-1+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\\&=1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+\cdots\end{align}

Concerning the other function, note that, since$$\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\cdots,$$and since$$\frac1{(1-z)^2}=\left(\frac1{1-z}\right)',$$you have$$\frac1{(1-z)^2}=1+2z+3z^2+4z^3+\cdots$$By the same argument,$$\frac1{(1-z)^3}=1+3z+6z^2+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2z^n+\cdots$$So,$$\frac1{(1+z^2)^3}=1-3z^2+6z^4-\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2z^{2n}+\cdots,$$and therefore\begin{align}\frac{1+z}{(1+z^2)^3}&=\frac1{(1+z^2)^3}+z\frac1{(1+z^2)^3}\\&=1+z-3z^2-3z^3+6z^4+6z^5-\cdots\end{align}